# onbeforeunload not working within unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote the following code to run the onbeforeunload within unload. However, this doesn't seem working. Does anyone know what's wrong about my code and anyway to make it work?

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    if ($('.submitAction').val() == "" && isChange) {
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    }
});

function confirmExit() {
    return "If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onunload` event is the [absolute last event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) that fires when the user navigates away from the page or closes the browser.

Binding to the `onbeforeunload` event *within* the `onunload` event would be pointless, as this event has already occurred (hence the name *onbeforeunload*).  The solution would be to bind to the `onbeforeunload` event *before* the event actually happens, such as when the page loads.

Something like this (untested):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if ($('.submitAction').val() == "" && isChange) {
       return "If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line returns a string:

```
return "If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
```

I think you  meant:

```
return window.confirm("If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?");
```

Comment: The `beforeunload` event actually lets you return a string, which is used to nicely prompt the user (or annoy them to buy Viagra)..

Comment: @MikeChristensen -- I'll be.  Ok, I learned my something new for today.